# Anyone successfully managed to get the CM4 to boot directly from a PCIe SSD?

Tags: bootloader, compute-module

I've been trying off and on for a few days to get the PCIE boot working on my CM4/CM4IO setup but without success.    No matter how I attempt to convince RPIOS or Ubuntu to install the latest firmware but the boot loader it always complains that its 'Not recent enough'.

Am sure I'm missing some arcane fact..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2021/raspberry-pi-can-boot-nvme-ssds-now will help?

Comment: Thanks Ive gone through everything I’ve found online,  problem I think with this this being a beta implementation currently.

Answer (score 1):

So it was fairly easy to follow the instructions for rpi-eeprom-update to install to the beta version the epprom code.   Which is covered here:-

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/booteeprom.md

That will get the RPI to the next stage which is reading the /boot filesystem on the SSD.   However for it to mount and boot of the SSD the boot loader firmware modules need to be updated..

I managed to get my CM4IO / CM4 to boot after copying the latest firmware from the raspberry pi firmware repository.

https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware.git

I then updated the ubuntu 21.04 boot instance I prefer to use because its 64 bit with the same files (/boot/firmware) and its now booting off the PCIe SSD as well.